# Help solving the initial value problem dy/dt = 2t/(y-t)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I am trying to solve the following initial value problem for this differential equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{2t}{y-t} , \hspace{20px} y(1) = 0$$

I have tried the substitution $v=\frac{y}{t}$ which transforms the ODE into a separable equation, but I don't think it was the best approach to solve this problem. Can you help me figuring out what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what exactly went wrong with your try $v=\frac{y}{t}$?

Comment: The substitution should work fine..

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{2t}{y-t} , \hspace{20px} y(1) = 0$$
Substitute $y=vt$:
$$v't+v = \frac{2}{v-1}
$$
$$v't = \frac{2-v^2+v}{v-1} 
$$
This differential equation is separable.